# Quorum Private Transactions and zk-SNARKS

Tags: quorum

In Quorum, understand that zk-Snarks is the technology behind Zero Security Layer (ZSL).

How does the ZSL relate to Quorum Private Transactions? Does ZSL enable private transactions or are they separate things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are separate things, but privacy modifications to Quorum allow Ethereum based smart contracts to benefit from ZSL as well. See this repo for an example:
https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum-examples/tree/zsl_geth1.6

Comment: Thanks! Read in the link that privateFor doesnt prevent double spend therefore zsl is required. Other benefits?

Comment: I'm not sure where you would read that. privateFor eliminates value transfers in Quorum, therefore if you reply on ether, you may continue to do so in all public cases. For ZSL please read this: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/zsl-q